# Setting values of an object's non-value members through reflection

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection, recursion

I am trying to write a very loosely coupled method to map values returned from a database and stored in a `DataTable` to properties of a custom object.  This works fine for all value type properties, but I am having trouble setting the properties of objects that are themselves properties of the main class.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    protected void AssignDataRowToFields(DataRow data, object currentClass = null)
    {
        string strPrefix = currentClass == null ? string.Empty : currentClass.GetType().Name;
        currentClass = currentClass ?? this;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = currentClass.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsValueType || typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
            {
                if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
                    pi.SetValue(this, data[strPrefix + pi.Name].ToString(), null);
                else if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
                    pi.SetValue(this, int.Parse(data[strPrefix + pi.Name].ToString()), null);
            }
            else
                this.AssignDataRowToFields(data, pi.GetValue(currentClass, null));
        }
    }
```

The final else where I recursively call `AssignDataRowToFields` is always returning `null` for `pi.GetValue(currentClass, null)`.  I have also tried `pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(currentClass, null)` but that also returns null.  Any help would be most appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:  All of the properties in question here are automatic properties of the form:

```
public ComplexType theProperty { get; private set; }
```

Comment: are the sub-objects already created or do you need to instantiate them first?

Comment: This occurs during the original instantiation of the parent object, so the sub-objects would need to be instantiated as well as assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your class constructor creates the sub-objects first.